# How to start two and more equal AsyncTaskLoaders with different args

Tags: android, loader

How to start two and more equal AsyncTaskLoaders(Android) with different arguments? I have class BaseLoader extends AsyncTaskLoaders and Class A extends BaseLoader. I want to init two A Loaders with different argument and handle both of them in onLoadFinished. Is it possible?

Comment: call `LoaderManager#initLoader` twice with different ids ?

Comment: Thanks, it works. I tried to do this before, but forget about "new A(this,args)" in my mainclass